Discord.py with Apache Kafka
I'm trying to pair Discord Bot (python) with Kafka's message broker.
I'm thinking about next scheme: balancer, which runs a bot, receives messages from users (by bot commands) and sets commands to other services.
Next component is an abstract server, which listens to balancer, processes message and send a reply back to balancer.
I have created a Bot and a Kafka server:
Balancer with code

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="localhost:29092")
consumer = KafkaConsumer('kt', bootstrap_servers="localhost:29092")
@client.command(name="kt") # kafka test
async def kt(ctx):
    data = {
        'message': ctx.message.content.split(" ")[0],
    }
    producer.send('kmmsf', json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"))

successfully send a message to my 2nd server.
Server with While-true loop consumed it, and send a callback:
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="localhost:29092")
consumer = KafkaConsumer('kmmsf', bootstrap_servers="localhost:29092")
while True:
    for message in consumer:
        print('consumed!')
        data = {
            'message': 'Hello World!'
        }
        producer.send('kt', json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"))


Problem is that I can't operate with server's response in balancer:
While-true loop don't works inside async def, and a construction like for message in consumer doesn't enter's a loop and throws a timeout error.
Thank you in advance!
